# Is there any library or way to develop simple spreadsheet in iPhone and save it?

Tags: iphone, xcode, spreadsheet

I am developing iPhone inventory management app.I have done all things but now my client want me to develop simple spreadsheet.I have been searching for library but i didn't find anything.I have found that iOS provide spreadsheet viewer using web view in iPhone.But its not support editing.Please help me, If anybody have any idea.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to make your own. I've never seen one.